# How to enter decimal numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script >

var a1 = parseInt(prompt("enter first number."));
var a2 = parseInt(prompt("enter second number."));
var od1 =a1+a2;
document.write( od1 );

</script>
```

if i try to enter 1.5 and 1.5 program will print 2 !

(1.5 + 1.5 is clearly 3, not 2)

so why can not I enter decimal numbers ?

what i need to add to be able to enter decimal numbers ??

Comment: Do you understand what `Int` is short for? Did you learn in school what an **integer** is?

Answer (score 4):

For that you have to use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat),

```
var a1 = parseFloat(prompt("enter first number."));
var a2 = parseFloat(prompt("enter second number."));
var od1 =a1+a2;
document.write(od1);
```

`parseInt` will neglect the decimal points whereas `parseFloat` will consider the decimal points during conversion from string to number.

Answer (score 2):

use parseFloat instead of parseInt.

Integers don't have decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert string numbers to numbers in same bases. They're quite frustrating to beginners. `Number` or the unary plus are often good enough.

```
var a1 = Number(prompt("enter first number."));
var a2 = Number(prompt("enter second number."));
//or
var a1 = +prompt("enter first number.");
var a2 = +prompt("enter second number.");
```